# (Scala) Lists that can contain lists as elements

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, nested-lists

I have been coding for two years now. I can't say I'm an expert.

I have taken a course in functional programming in which we used Common Lisp. I heard a lot of great things about Scala, as a "*new*" language and wanted to learn it. I read a book for the basics and wanted to rewrite all the code we did in Lisp into Scala. Almost all the code was going through lists and this is where I found a problem. Most of the problems I could solve with recursively going through the list where I set it as `List[Any]`  - for example:

```
def reverse(thelist: List[Any]):List[Any].....
```

but as I've found out there isn't a specific way for checking whether the head of the list is a list itself except for `.isInstanceOf[List[Any]]`

This was OK at first, but now I have a problem. `Any` isn't very specific, especially with comparing elements. If I wanted to have an equivalent list with, let's say, only `Int`, I can create a `List[Int]` which can only take an `Int` value as an element, none of which can be List[Int] itself. The other way, writing `List[List[Int]]` has the same problem, but in reverse, because every element has to be a `List`.

As a solution I've tried setting the original list as `List[Either[Int,List[Int]]]`, but that only created more problems, as now I have to constantly write `.isInstanceOf` and `.asInstanceOf` in all of my ifs and recursive calls, which is time-consuming and makes the code harder to understand. But even `List[Either[Int,List[Int]]]` is a temporary solution, because it only goes one level deep. A list can contain a list that can contain a list... and so on.

Does Scala offer a more elegant solution I am not yet aware of, such as using classes or objects in some way, or a simple elegant solution, or am I stuck with writing this kind of code? To make my question more specific, is there a way in Scala to define a list that can, but doesn't have to contain a list of the same kind as an element?

Comment: Please clean up your formatting. The readability is lacking.

Comment: Reformatted. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scala isn't just Common Lisp with different syntax. Using lists for everything is something specific to Lisp, not something you do in other languages.

In Scala it's not normal to ever use a heterogeneous list — `List[Any]` — for anything. You certainly can if you want, but it isn't the way Scala code is normally written. It certainly isn't the kind of code you should be writing when you are only just beginning to learn the language.

A list that contains a mixture of numbers and lists isn't really a list — it's a tree. In Scala, we don't represent trees using `List` at all — we define a proper tree data type. Any introductory Scala text contains examples of this. (See, for example, the expression trees in [chapter 15 of *Programming in Scala*](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html).)

As for your `reverse` example, in Scala we would normally never write:

```
def reverse(thelist: List[Any]): List[Any]
```

rather, we write:

```
def reverse[T](theList: List[T]): List[T]
```

which works on `List[Any]` but also works on more specific types such as `List[Int]`.

If you insist on doing it the other way, you aren't really learning Scala — you're fighting with it. Anytime you think you need `Any` or `List[Any]`, there is better, more idiomatic, more Scala-like solution.

It's also never normal to use `asInstanceOf` or `isInstanceOf` in Scala code. They have long obscure names on purpose — they're not intended to be used except in rare situations.

Instead, use pattern matching. It does the equivalent of `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf` for you, but in much more concise and less error-prone way. Again, any introductory Scala text should have good coverage of what pattern matching is and how to use it (e.g. [chapter 15 again](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the response, cleared things up a bit. As a follow-up I would have to ask, does this mean that the equivalent to Lisp's lists in Scala would be Trees?

Comment: @Nik.S. not quite. Lips uses lists for everything, sometimes it's good, sometimes it's not. Scala (and a lot of other languages) pick specific data structure for a particular problem.

Comment: I've added links to chapter 15 of _Programming in Scala_, which shows how to use a set of related case classes to represent (as an example of a particular kind of tree) expression trees. In Lisp you would use lists for this; in Scala you take an entirely different approach that doesn't involve "equivalents" of things from Lisp at all. It would be better if you stopped thinking in terms of equivalents and approached Scala on its on terms. Mentally translating everything into Language A is not a good way to learn Language B, whatever A and B are.